# How to separate POLYGONS from MULTIPOLYGON in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I was checking `RGeo` and did not find a way to check if a provided data in a `GeoJSON` in `MultiPolygon` is a inner ring or exterior ring (I was checking this to just separate out MultiPolygon into separate polygons from a `MultiPolygon`. Is there a direct way to approach this?